# Error while trying to run Reactive Native: Run Android on device in VSC

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

So I am trying to start react native project on my phone, but I got this error:

Stack: Error: Failed to run the application in Android (error code 104): Error while executing command '"\Users\mac\Library\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb" devices': Command failed: "\Users\mac\Library\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb" devices
The system cannot find the path specified.

I am using Visual Studio Code, and command React Native: Run Android on device from React Native tools